# Tensorflow model with image + number as input

Tags: python, tensorflow, merge, conv-neural-network

I have a Tensorflow CNN model which accepts an image (of fixed size) as input, and the outputs are 5 numbers (the last layer of the model is a Dense layer with 5 neurons, linear activation). So naturally for management of the data I have a spreadsheet containing information of the training images, followed by the 5 columns of numbers. Now I am considering training a separate model which takes as input, an image + 4 of the numbers, and predicts the last number. Any ideas on how to do this?

I have seen [the Funtional API page](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional#models_with_multiple_inputs_and_outputs) and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51739016/tensorflow-training-model-on-image-and-text-features-with-multi-class-outputs). But I am not sure how to combine the image with the numbers. Concatenate does not seem to be appropriate. Should the 4 numbers come in as Dense neurons instead? If so then that would occur after the Conv2D layers.

Any suggestions and references are most welcome.

Comment: If you can already predict the fifth number why are you trying to create a model that JUST predict the fifth number?

Comment: @AnuragDhadse The prediction for the fifth number as of now is not good enough. Perhaps knowing the other four numbers can help give better predictions for the fifth number?

Comment: Assume I am able to get the first four numbers from an image using other methods. (More time consuming but possible)

Comment: This problem looks more of `Image captioning`. Feed the image along with caption(number) to model and predict the image with caption. You can feed image and number to model get number as a result. Take look at tensorflow [image captioning tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/image_captioning). Thanks!